# How to generalize a jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I use some jQuery to highlight form fields. But not the input field itself gets highlighted but its parent. And I want to specify those parents.

Here the parent is div and it works fine

```
$("div input").focus(function () {
        $(this).parent().addClass("focus");
});
```

But I want to specify the parent "td" too like this

```
$("div,td  input").focus(function () {
        $(this).parent().addClass("focus");
});
```

But this does not work. Only td fields get the focus attribute! Any idea how to handle this?

Comment: In what way does it not work? What does your HTML look like?

Comment: I edited my question. TD gets focus but div not!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A comma will completely separate two selectors; you need to specify `input` twice:

```
$('div input, td input').focus(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass("focus");
});
```

Alternatively, if you don't have many `<input>`s that *don't* match this criteria, you can make it a little neater:

```
$('input').focus(function() {
    $(this).parent('div, td').addClass('focus');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that with `,` you create a complete new selector !

You are looking for

```
    $('div input, td input').focus(function() {
       $(this).parent().addClass("focus");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting all input fields parent then you can do something like this:-

```
$('input').focus(function () {
        $(this).parent().addClass('focus');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the child selector:

```
$("div > input, td > input")
.focus(function () {
  $(this).parent().addClass("focus");
})
.blur(function () {
  $(this).parent().removeClass("focus");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

```
$('td input, div input').focus(function () {
    $(this).parent().addClass("focus");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you are selecting `div` AND `td input` rather than `div input` AND `td input`. The comma is used as a separator of selectors.

You can use the following if you don't have any other `input` fields:

```
$("input")
```

or if you need to limit to `div` an `td` then:

```
$("div input, td input");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').parent('td').addClass('focus');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td input').add().parent().doSOmething()
```

Comment: There's no point in specifying `a:has(b) b`, it's equivalent to `a b`.

Comment: true, i started with just the td, before realizing OP wanted both elements